# DoJo Toolkit additional headers not set on request

Tags: javascript, dojo, http-headers

I'm using DoJo 1.6.1 for accessing my REST web service. To get the response in JSON I need to set the `Aceept` header field to `application/json`.

According to the DoJo documentation this is done by setting the `headers` property on the request, like to following:

```js
var xhrArgs = {
    url: "http://localhost/myservice",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json" },
    handleAs: "json",
    load: successCallback,
    error: errorCallback
}

var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
```

I also used `dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs);` with the same issue: accept is of the value `*/*` on the server side. I'm using Firefox 5.0.1 (also tried with Safari and Firefox on Windows).

Any suggestions what the problem is?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }` is correct. Are you using Firebug to see the actual headers and confirmed that they're incorrect?

Comment: Yes, also checked that with Firebug and the request contains */* as accept header field.